# Is a graduate homework question acceptable?

Tags: discussion, homework

I just stumbled on a [graduate level question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11850/contract-theory-question) which is not marked or mentioned as a homework question, though the OP even posted the whole picture of the question without detailing his attempts. I am just wondering if a graduate level homework question like that one is acceptable to our forum.

Answer (score 5):

Only if it follows the usual rules: the asker must have made some attempt to answer it themselves, they must show us what they've done, and they must explain which concept or aspect of it they're having trouble with.

The asker has done those things. However, as their actual question is just an image, that's useless for search engines, so the question should be closed anyway.